# How can I add a information for a view and apply it to all the similar views

Tags: magento-1.7, category, store-view, language

My Magento is divided in multiple stores. One for each country that we sell too. And in views that are the different languages.

Here is a screenshot of my setup:

[image: My Magento setup]

My question is: can I change something for all the English views at the same time without needing to repeat the process over and over again?

Also when I create a category in "All Store Views" in the section "Categories", why is it not applying it to all the other views?

**UPDATE**

Here is an example:

I have a category named: Business

I want to use Affaires as the French name for my category.

The problem is that I have to change it for each country that as a French view.

Isn't there a way to automate this?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what it is that you're changing in all of the english store views? Content? Static blocks?

Comment: Well one example is categories. It is actually my second question. But also in the configuration the Title of the pages and the links will be different for each languages... Is there a way to have a config for all the English views and French views etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can't (easily)
One idea is to add an translation option to the title inside the template.

So this means:

```
<?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

will turn into:

```
<?php echo $this->__($_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name')); ?>
```

And use a translate.csv to translate all the elements.

An other way is to write an observer for the *_save_after event and than match it with the locale code of the specific store. But its a little tricky since you cannot differ the titles anymore between websites.

(e.g. store1 you want to have the name: "category1 is awesome" and in store2 you want "category1 is great". This is not possible after using applying the observer)